# If $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions, then does $f_n$ being integrable imply $\lim \int f_n d\mu=\int \lim f_n$? Can we use Luzin's Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Further let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions.
>
> Does $f_n$ being integrable imply that $\lim \int f_n d\mu=\int \lim f_n$?

My approach:
My idea would be to get a contradiction by using Luzin's theorem. Let $\epsilon >0$, then there exists a closed set $E \subseteq X$ and $f_n$ restricted to $E$ is continuous on $E$

Now, we know that if $f_n$ are continuous, we can not interchange limit and integral.
So by considering $\int_{E} f_n d\mu$, we get a contradiction.

Is this enough to disprove said statement at the beginning. I know there are counterexamples but I wanted to know if I could use Luzins Theorem in thet way.

Does my approach even work?
Because there is a slight difference in a function g, such that $g_{|E}$ to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and to be continuous on only $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This does not even hold with $f,f_1,f_2,\dots \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the Riemann integral, let alone on arbitrary measure spaces. For example, take
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 \quad &\text{if } n \leq x \leq n+1, \\
0 \quad &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.